# Переназначение клавиш

Tags: debian, xorg

Дистрибутив **Debian Squeeze**. Появилось желание переназначить клавиши таким образом:

1. **Control** на **Caps Lock**, а **Caps Lock** соответственно на **Control**
2. **Mod4** на **Return**, а **Return** соответственно на **Mod4**

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать. Может быть через правку ~/.xmodmaprc? Если да, то что прописать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению нет возможности попробовать,но может это вам поможет:
 http://www.it-simple.ru/?p=1026